# Webpack config from npm script

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have two scripts in package.json setup as follows,

```
    "scripts": {
"webpackDevServer": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.config.dev.js --progress --colors",
    "webPack": "babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=webpack.config.dev.js"
}
```

When I execute it with > npm run webPack

I get this error,

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\Xpert\WebstormProjects\Re\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at C:\Users\Xpert\WebstormProjects\Re\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:155:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Xpert\WebstormProjects\Re\node_modules\babel-cli\lib\_babel-node.js:156:7)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webPack"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! siv@0.0.1 webPack: `babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=webpack.config.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the siv@0.0.1 webPack script 'babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=webpack.config.dev.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the simprov package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config=webpack.config.dev.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs si
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls simprov
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Xpert\WebstormProjects\Re\npm-debug.log
```

The same happens when I do > npm run webpackDevServer

What am I doing wrong here?

-Thank you.

Comment: `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")` is a shell script, are you accidentally using non-JavaScript in your webpack config?

Comment: It's from here, https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server 
 seems like that statement does not work with windows and is enviromnet constrained.

Comment: Same error has occurred in my case also but updating webpack and webpack-dev-server to the latest version has removed that error for me. Only difference between my and your implementation is "babel-node" which I haven't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

babel-node at the beginning is unnecessary, just run "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"

Answer (score 0):

Windows can not resolve proper *webpack-dev-server* file extension to use ((

Invoke `*.js` explicitly:

```
"node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config=webpack.config.dev.js --progress"
```

Or run it through `CLI`

```
"webpack-dev-server --config=webpack.config.dev.js --progress --color"
```